# ASP Classic - moving value to variable

Tags: variables, asp-classic

Under the following condition I am trying to move a value of "E" to the
BillMeType variable but it is not working.

```
<% if TransactionGateway = "" then %>
<% BillMeType = "E" %>
<% end if %>
```

Comment: "it is not working" is not a good description of a problem. What isn't working? What do you expect to happen that does not? How are you trying to use the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way `BillMeType` can not be set to "E" (using your code sample) is if `TransactionGateway` is not equal to an empty string.  Is `TransactionGateway` something that may *appear* to be an empty string - i.e. **NULL**?

Also, you don't need to do all of the context switching if you are still in a code block.  Your code could be rewritten to:

```
<% 
If TransactionGateway = "" Then
  BillMeType = "E"
End If 
%>
```

IMHO, this is much more readable.

Also, I edited your title.  ASP.NET and ASP Classic are two completely different things.  The word "Classic" comes from the fact that this version of ASP was pre-.NET.  ASP Classic is (generally) written in VBScript, whereas .NET is written in a CLR language (C#, VB.NET, etc.).  I

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`<% If TransactionGateway = ""
Then BillMeType = "E"
End If 
cstr(BillMeType)
response.Write(BillMeType)%>`

Comment: Now this is just a complete mess. Please test the code before posting.